# background music

Tags: objective-c, ios, avfoundation, avplayer

(using AVFoundation.framework)

```
#import "AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h"
```

So I got a problem, I tried this code first in init method of my class (that is the  one that is loaded first)

```
NSString* soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"music" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL* soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
AVAudioPlayer* player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
player.numberOfLoops=-1;
[player play];
```

But it didn't work, than I decided to do it in thread:
in init method:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(playMusic) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

and method itself:

```
-(void) playMusic {
    NSString* soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"music" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL* soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
    AVAudioPlayer* player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
    player.numberOfLoops=-1;
    [player play];
}
```

it is declared in *.h file of course. It also didn't work.

I tried to debug, on line

```
}
```

of playMusic method the file is played for 2 or 3 seconds and then stops. It isn't played without debug. What is the problem?

Comment: Make the AVAudioPlayer an instance variable of the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AVAudioPlayer will be deallocated immediately. You need to retain the player.
So make the AVAudioPlayer an instance variable of the class.